# Adding event clicks to POIs in Android Augmented Reality framework?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application based on Android AR framework : http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework

Can anyone please suggest how to add click to the POIs or icons in camera view to view address of the POIs?

Answer (score 1):

When a marker is clicked, the markerTouched(Marker marker) method is called in the Demo class.
On 4 October was integrated.